# Use Excel Userform info for file name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question about userforms. Currently I have a forum button set up with a macro that will show the user a userform, where the user will enter data, and then save 5 out of the 6 sheets as a new book. I want to make it so the file name is based off the value of ProjectName (Me.ProjectName.Value), the first field in the userform. Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data List")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a Name number
If Trim(Me.ProjectName.Value) = "" Then
Me.ProjectName.SetFocus
MsgBox "Please complete the form"
Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.ProjectName.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.ProjectNumber.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.SPVComp.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.Contact.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.ProjMan.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.PODate.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.PONumber.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.PRNumber.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Me.EstTime.Value


MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"



Sheets(Array("Document Data", "Invoice data", "Hours", "Summary", "Invoice")).Copy
fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Filename:=Me.ProjectName.Value, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=52


'clear the data
Me.ProjectName.Value = ""
Me.ProjectNumber.Value = ""
Me.SPVComp.Value = ""
Me.Contact.Value = ""
Me.ProjMan.Value = ""
Me.PODate.Value = ""
Me.PONumber.Value = ""
Me.PRNumber.Value = ""
Me.EstTime.Value = ""
Me.ProjectName.SetFocus
```

The error I get is name argument not found on Filename:=. I'm still very new to VBA so I'm not exactly sure what to do here. Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `Application.GetSaveAsFileName` doesn't support a parameter `FileName`. If you want to suggest the user an initial file name, please use named parameter `InitialFilename` instead.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff195734.aspx)